# Convert type str (with number and words) column into int pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column that contains type str of both numbers and words:

ex.

```
['2','3','Amy','199','Happy']
```

And I want to convert all "str number" into int and remove (the rows with) the "str words".

So my expected output would be a list like below:

```
[2, 3, 199]
```

Since I have a pandas dataframe, and this supposed to be one of the columns, it would be even better if it could be a `Series` as follows:

```
0      2.0
1      3.0
3    199.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @rko He wants to remove the non integer-like values, like in my answer.

Comment: Completely missed the removal of that

Comment: Is your input data a pandas dataframe or a list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you mentioned you have a column (a series), so let's say it's called `s`:

```
s = pd.Series(['2', '3', 'Amy', '199', 'Happy'])
```

Then after assigning, just do [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and put the parameter of `errors='coerce'`. Then, remove the `NaN`s with [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
print(pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').dropna())
```

Then the above code will output:

```
0      2.0
1      3.0
3    199.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

without using pandas as you are supplying an array

```
import re
data = ['2','3','Amy','199','Happy']
for item in data:
    print (*re.findall(r'\d+',item))
```

will give

```
2
3

199
```

and

```
import re
data = ['2','3','Amy','199','Happy']
out = []
for item in data:
    m = str(*re.findall(r'\d+',item))
    if m != "":
        out.append(int(m))
print (out)
```

will give

```
[2, 3, 199]
```

Comment: I think he wants the result in a list with only the integer-like values

Comment: I thought he said column, so I assumed df

Comment: agreed, here are int, not floats.  And here is a more general solution that will work with arrays...  just another way of skinning a cat

Answer (score 1):

You can use isnumeric to filter out nonnumeric items.

```
s = pd.Series(['2','3','Amy','199','Happy'])
print(s[s.str.isnumeric()].astype(int))
```

Output:

```
0      2
1      3
3    199
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nice answer +1, In my answer I use `pd.to_numeric` and here you directly filter.